# Rails4, Exception Notifier not change sender_address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, exception-notification

Our Rails Application using ExceptionNotifier Gem

and change configuration file

Exception Mail is working good

But sender mail is not  Noreply < noreply@our_domain.com >

Always sender is my email_address

My production.rb file is

```
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
   :email => {
     :email_prefix => "[Exception ",
     :sender_address => %{"Noreply" <noreply@our_domain.com>},
     :exception_recipients => %w{my_email@gmail.com}
   }
```

And setup_mailer.rb file is

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "our_domain.com",
  :user_name => "my_eamail@our_domain.com",
  :password => "PASSWORD",
  :authentication => "login",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true

}
```

why sender address not change???

Comment: I couldn't find a newer document.  I don't think much has changed.  Please see here: http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you authenticate using the Gmail SMTP account, Gmail will override the sender to your Gmail account. They don't allow you to use their SMTP to send emails from a different domain.

Comment: I change username "my_email@domain.com" and domain.com is my custom gmail apps mail.  and It also sender is my email_address. :(

Comment: and then how to change and  send norepy@doamin.com ?

Answer (score 0):

try below code in `production.rb`(Assuming you want to work in production) and **hard code** it....

```
 ##added exception notification gem
 MyApp::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
   :email => {
     :email_prefix => "[MyApp_Error] ",
     :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@myApp.com>},
     :exception_recipients => %w{your_desired_email@gmail.com}
   }
```

i works for me....

Comment: It Also not change sender address... mailUser name is change ("Noreply <my_email@our_domain.com>") i will try more :)

Answer (score 0):

#TRY THIS in :sender_address write your own name and mail address

```
 :sender_address => %{"Username" <useremailid@xyzmail.com>},
```